# Error cryptography Fernet read token from file

Tags: python, cryptography

I create the key and I encrypt the message send by user, and store this message in a file and after i try to decrypt this message in the file, but i get this error `cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken`. I don't use the time for the token and  I have also converted in byte after.

My code is:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet



key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)



def encry():
    global f
    what = input("What i need to encrypt?")
    what_b = str.encode(what)
    token = f.encrypt(what_b)
    print("key generated")
    print("encrypted")
    file1=open("string.txt", "w")
    file1.write(str(token))
    file1.close()
    file2=open("key.txt", "w")
    file2.write(str(key))
    file2.close()

def decry():
    global f
    print("decrypted")
    file1=open("string.txt", "r").read()
    file_de=str.encode(file1)
    file2=open("de.txt", "w")
    what_d = f.decrypt(file_de)
    file1.close()
    file2.write(str(what_d))
    file2.close()


choose = input("Do you want, encrypt or decrypt?" + " " + "(e/d)")
if choose == "e":
    encry()
elif choose == "d":
    decry()
else:
    print("Nothing to do")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from the way you write and read the message and the key to and from the files. Indeed, the encrypted text and the keys are not `strings`, but `byte strings` and need to be treated in a different way.

In your case, when reading and writing it is enough to specify that you do it in *binary mode* and you can do it by adding the *b* flag. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for more detailed information.

Moreover, in your decrypt you also need to read the key from the file.

```
def encry():

    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    f = Fernet(key)

    what = "example"
    what_b = str.encode(what)
    token = f.encrypt(what_b)

    with open("string.txt", "wb") as f1, open("key.txt", "wb") as f2:
        f1.write(token)
        f2.write(key)


def decry():
    with open("string.txt", "rb") as f1, open("key.txt", "rb") as f2:
        token = f1.read()
        key = f2.read()

    f = Fernet(key)
    what_d = str(f.decrypt(token),'utf-8') #converting back to string

encry()
decry()
```

Comment: Thnak you, your answer i helped me to understand where the problem is